# Where did Arkham Knight get his army?

Tags: dc, batman, video-games, batman-arkham-knight, arkham-series

In the last installment of the Arkham trilogy we find out that the mysterious mercenary leader with an army who calls himself Arkham Knight is no other than

> Jason Todd - previous Robin captured, tortured and presumably killed by Joker

That would explain his training, abilities and knowledge of Batman, but it doesn't explain where he got such a huge army with several hundreds of drone tanks and helicopters.

So where did he get the money / manpower to launch a full scale attack?

Comment: Having been a Batman fan in my preteen years, during the period in which Jason Todd was killed, the fact that they brought him back to life is surprisingly annoying to me.  I know that comic book characters don't stay dead, but still... we actually got to vote on whether Jason should die, and the result was conclusive:  everyone wanted him dead.  Grr...

Comment: From up his sleevie?

Comment: @WadCheber: “everyone wanted him dead” —  5,343 people wanted him dead enough to call the 1-900 number; 5,271 wanted him alive enough to call the other 1-900 number. “Everyone” may not be the right word.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: For a man with his skills & charisma, obtaining followers or resources would be quite easy.**

---

Although their exact origin is unknown, the [**Arkham Knight Militia**](http://arkhamcity.wikia.com/wiki/Arkham_Knight's_Militia) would appear to be a pre-existing mercenary unit that ended up working for [The Arkham Knight](http://arkhamcity.wikia.com/wiki/Arkham_Knight).

We know that

> Jason Todd spent several months in Venezuela, presumably recovering from his time with The Joker and planning his revenge on Batman.

It's safe to assume that he found the mercenaries at this time and convinced them to work for him, possibly with promises of future riches (looting Gotham City, maybe?). Once he had the manpower, obtaining money or further resources would be relatively easy.

Another possibility is that the antagonist

> had access to many of [Bruce Wayne's](http://arkhamcity.wikia.com/wiki/Bruce_Wayne) secrets. This could have possibly included bank accounts and/or hidden reserves of money & resources. Not to mention his own skills, which would make theft of said valuables quite easy.

*And here's a nice picture...*
[image]

Comment: One of the incidental dialogue bursts in-game mentions that, at least according to Thug #28947, Lex Luthor is one of many investors in their operation.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to answer my own question, but today I managed to get all the Riddler's trophies and that unlocked some more background story.

Arkham Knight got the money

> after he aproached Dr. Crane (Scarecrow) with a plan and specifically asked for 3 billion dollars for which to buy army and drones. We can only assume Crane already had this kind of money or held another meeting with the criminal underworld.

Answer (score 0):

To ask to answer your question, Arkham knight was good at negotiations with a private army and mercenary and there is also a good source in south America he asked for funds in Mexico from cartels and many more it is also to be rumored that lex Luthor funded him with Tech and weapons and a lot of money to raise an army. For Arkham knight to raise such a high ground force army he paid a lot of cash for private armies and mercenaries to join him and that is where he started in Venezuela where he rallied such a huge army that can take a town and city but not as Los Angeles and new york since he does not have that much ground troops to be placed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have a source that you can cite for this?  It seems to contradict an existing answer that's based on the game's storyline.